# Magento 2 - How to add currency switched to navigation

Tags: magento, magento2.2

I'm willing to move currency switcher in Magento 2.2 to become last item of navigation, any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way you can do this, another way is to use multistore or International Module

but i prefer Multistore route if you would like my options then got to the following link http://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-stores-in-magento2/